# How do I change div positions from horizontally aligned to vertically aligned when a condition is true?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a sidebar which can change size if the user presses the minimize button.
In this sidebar a battery (which is an SvgIcon) and a text showing its charge is placed.

I have two problems:

1. Making sure "Battery: X%" and the battery are horizontally aligned and still fit within the sidebar div.
2. Moving and changing the text to be horizontally aligned above the SvgIcon battery when the sidebar is minimized.

I'm drawing a blank on how to go about this.
Currently I have a div containing two other divs with text and svg in them respectively. The div structure looks pretty much as below, but I can't figure out the CSS.

```
<div id='batteryContainer'>
  <div id='batteryText'>
     {this.expanded && 'Battery: ' + this.batteryCharge + '%'}
     {!this.expanded && this.batteryCharge + '%'}
  </div>
  <div id='batterySvg'>
     <SvgIcon
        component={batterySvgIcon}
        viewBox={'0 0 y z'}
     />
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS is currently

```
#batteryContainer{    
    position: absolute;    
    bottom: 50px; }  
#batteryText{   
    position: relative;   
    display: inline-block;   
    align-items: center; } 
#batterySvg{   
    position: relative;   
    display: inline-block;   
    align-items: center; }
```

The behavior shown in the picture is what I'm trying to accomplish. Currently it's close to correct while expanded, but I can't figure out how to code it to get the change I want when minimizing.
[image: Sidebar when expanded and minimized]

Thank you for any help!

Comment: "It looks pretty much as below, but I can't figure out the CSS." Are you referring to what the code looks like or what your actual result looks like in the image? Is the image what you currently have or what you want? What CSS, can you include what you've tried?

Comment: Sorry @DrewReese I realize that was a bit unclear. I've edited my question now in an attempt to provide more accurate information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use Flex box, when the side bar is closed you need to set the container's flex-direction property to column

```
#batteryContaier {
  display : flex,
  flex-direction: column,
}
```

and then when side bar is open the flex-direction must be row

```
#batteryContaier {
    flex-direction : row;
}
```

for more about flex box read this article

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thank you, this sounds like what I'm looking for. I'll attempt it first thing tomorrow when I get to work. I'm not quite sure how that's done though, can I overwrite the css from inside the js file on the state change?

Comment: Yes i guess, but pay attention that way you don't wanna use id for selecting element , you have to make two classes one for when it's open and one for when it's closed , then put a conditional in class attribute of your element ans use your state to switch between classes. I hope that makes sense

Comment: Thank you. This does exactly what I want. 

I was a bit unsure what you meant first, so this is how I wrote it if anyone else is unsure about the syntax of that class change
`<div
     className={this.expanded? 'batteryContainer-row' : 'batteryContainer-column'}
>`

Comment: I'm glad i could help , I strongly recommend reading that article i mentioned in the answer. I'm a front end dev and I use flex box on a daily basis, it is very important in terms of responsive design , wish you the best.